# Azure Devops Package Retention Policy - Packages deleted

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package

Currently we are working with a large list of applications. Some of which have been running for years.

As the package feed is growing steadily in size, we decided to turn on the retention policies to have old versions deleted. This works like a charm.

However, when one of the older applications required an update, we also updated the packages.
But, as an old package version that was used before got cleaned up, the package manager is not able to uninstall the old version, and install the new version.

Luckily we could revert the deleted version from the recycle bin and continue as normal, but what would be the preferred way to fix this?

Obviously the easiest would be to update all applications when a new package version is released, but we are still constructing that list.

The only other option I can think of would be manually adjusting project files to remove the old version and then use the package manager to install the new version

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the easiest way is to update all applications when a new package version is released. Since you're still building this list, maybe in the meantime you can adjust your retention policy to retain older package versions for a longer period of time.

If you need to adjust for a long time and will exceed the retention policy's number of days, and you are concerned that the retention policy will remove required packages, you may consider [purchasing some Azure Artifacts capacity](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/) and stop the retention policy until all applications are updated.